# Проблема с социальной аутентификацией Django, rest_framework_social_oauth2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, auth, oauth, oauth2

При конвертации токена от ВК в JWT токен (библиотека rest_framework_social_oauth2, делал как [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix3DlB48d1g&list=PLF-NY6ldwAWqSxUpnTBObEP21cFQxNJ7C)) прилетает ошибка:

```
IntegrityError at /api/v0-1-0/auth/convert-token/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
```

Может быть, из-за того, что в моей модели пользователя обязательно поле "email"?